# How to get the selected element in a diagram trough and Add-In in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, add-in, enterprise-architect

I'm currently developing an Add-In with a variety of functions, one of them to align ports in a diagram horizontally.

Therefore, I need to get the current selected element/ port in a diagram ( in this case Hand(Port4)) as an "anchor" element so that the other selected ports align themselves to the same x - coordinate.

Example diagram I'm working on
[image: Example diagram I'm working on]

In EA itself, it works wonderfully with

```
Select Object_ID, Name from t_object where Object_id = #CurrentElementID#
```

Going into my Add-In (that I'm developing in C# in Visual Studio 2022), I thought that I could do the same with a SQLQuery a la

```
String selectedPort = repository.SQLQuery("Select Object_ID, Name from t_object where Object_ID = #CurrentElementID# ");
```

Which gives me a syntax error at `Object_ID = #CurrentElementID#` and I don't know why tbh. I found this [link](https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=41937.0) where #OBJECTID# was suggested but that didn't work either.

How do I get around this problem and get the `port.top` - value so that I can align the other ports to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the #-enclosed keywords except in custom SQL (from the search builder). So you have to  use `EADiagram.SelectedObjects` which is a collection. `repository.GetCurrentDiagram` will give you the according diagram object. You need to check if the collection contains only a single element and use that. From here you can find the elementId/ObjectId and place it in your query.

Since you are using an add-in it's probably easier to use [EA_OnContextItemChanged](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/add-ins___scripting/ea_oncontextitemchanged.html) which points you to the port you right clicked to start the add-in.

Comment: Ah damn, I was afraid i couldnt do that. The collection stores all the elements (or ports in my case) that are selected based on when it was created, so the last created object is first in the collection. For that case my algorithm to align the ports works based on the coordinates of the last element, but it would be more benefical if it would work with the highlighted element as seen in the picture. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: You can also use the ContextItem (or what it was called) to get the Port you were starting from since you use an add-in.

Comment: See my amendment in the answer.

Comment: Thanks to your help, i finally solved it! It isnt a really pretty solution but it works.